# Xamarin forms margin using dynamic resource

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Does anyone know if its possible to change margin dynamically using DynamicResource or some other way in Xamarin Forms?

I have tried the following but the margin does not get applied.

XAML File

```
<Style x:Key="LogoStyle" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{DynamicResource LogoMargin}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Code Behind

```
Application.Current.Resources["LogoMargin"] = "40,20";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Margin` property (same as the `Padding`) is of type `Thickness` thus:

```
Application.Current.Resources["LogoMargin"] = new Thickness(40,20);
```

Or in xaml

```
<Thickness x:Key="LogoMargin">40,20</Thickness>
```

Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding#specifying-a-thickness